# is there an expression to describe “something/someone that is more real than the original item/thing”

Tags: phrases, expressions, descriptive-grammar

I’m looking for a word or a phrase that describes the following:

“something/someone that is more real than the original item/thing”

I am looking for something specific, if possible! Thank you!

Comment: Please add a description of what you mean by real, add some examples, and provide a sample sentence where you would use this word.

Comment: [More Catholic than the Pope](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/more_Catholic_than_the_Pope)?